# Filtering output of `tree` command

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing many sub-directories, each with lots of files having different extensions.

Is it possible for me to filter the output of the  `tree` command so that files having certain extensions like say `.log` and `.msh` or certain named directories are not in the output

Consider the example below

```
    .
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── bar.log
    │   ├── blahblah
    │   │   └── blah.txt
    │   ├── hello.txt
    │   └── test.msh
    ├── foo.log
    ├── out
    ├── test.py
    └── test.txt

    2 directories, 8 files
```

I would like to filter **away** certain directories (and obviously *their* contents) and files having certain extensions. For instance I would like to filter away the contents of directory `blahblah` and all files having extensions `.msh` and `.log`

So I would like the output to be

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── hello.txt
├── out
├── test.py
└── test.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: It's a **flag** they're looking for.  They're either gonna know it or they won't. If they don't how are they gonna *"show code"*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`tree` command has `-I` option that allows you to filter out both files and directories that match the given pattern.

```
tree -I 'blahblah|*.msh|*.log'
```

Comment: This helps to remove but not to include, how to include only some extensions?

Comment: @PabloPazos `-P` option should do that.

Comment: and `--prune` to get rid of now-empty directories.